# Putting regular expressions in strings

Tags: javascript, html, regex, node.js, escaping

I am trying to dynamically create a javascript file B using a javascript file A (written in Node.js) by writing a string from A to a `.js` file B. I want to use regular expressions in the javascript file B. This requires me to put the regex functions for B in a string in A. However, whenever I use the backslash (escape character), file A interprets the regex function immediately, instead of treating it as a string.

Some code to help in understanding my problem:

```
var mongodata = "Some String with square and curly brackets ]}{]]},]},}{}{{}},{[[][,][,";
mongodata = 'var mongodata = ' + mongodata + ';\n function setData(){mongodata = mongodata.replace(/\[ /g,"").replace(/\] \},/g,"</td></tr>").replace(/\] \}/g,"</td></tr>"); document.getElementById("mongodata").innerHTML = mongodata;}';
```

That `mongodata` string is intended to be used as the content of a dynamically created `.js` file.

I understand the wording of this question may be slightly confusing. Please let me know if more clarification is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your string, just like the `\n` character, all the other backslashed expressions are being evaluated, so you must escape the backslashes. In other words, write a RegExp that outputs a RegExp. The proper way of escaping the backslashes themselves is `\\\` , but you might need to escape other characters as well to prevent their evaluation.

Comment: Thank you! You were very close. You would actually need a set of three backslashes (`\\\`). But thanks for pushing me in the right direction. +1 +Accept.

Comment: Glad to help, and sorry for the misleading, I'm not an expert of RegExp. Feel free to edit my answer!!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your problem, but maybe put the string being assigned to mongodata in escaped quotes:

`var mongodata = "\'Some String with square and curly brackets ]}{]]},]},}{}{{}},{[[][,][,\'";`

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a lottery this one.  I too don't quite understand your question.

You can escape all of the RegEx special characters (. * ? [ ] Etc).  You can also dynamically create RegEx operators using:

```
var objRegEx = new RegExp( pattern, modifiers );
```

Like I say, lottery... stab in the dark...